# Unable to send email - ISPConfig / Roundcube

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta, roundcube, ispconfig

I have got ISPConfig installed on my VPS and I'm trying to set up the email function.

My Server IP is 146.71.76.30 and hostname is set to dutyhosts.tk

Whenever I try and send an email via Roundcube I am getting the below error in the mail logs

Can someone advise on what I have missed or need to sort?

```
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=11098, secured, session=<DBQKD7Otrtx/AAAB>
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts postfix/pickup[10367]: A6C04A558D: uid=33 from=<support@dutyhosts.tk>
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts dovecot: imap(support@dutyhosts.tk): Logged out in=451 out=640
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts postfix/cleanup[11095]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:11332: Connection refused
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts postfix/cleanup[11095]: A6C04A558D: message-id=<f003feab44aba7e7cd98fba5afbea994@dutyhosts.tk>
Aug 25 12:44:06 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: A6C04A558D: from=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, size=549, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:44:08 dutyhosts dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=11102, secured, session=<bZwnD7OtwNx/AAAB>
Aug 25 12:44:08 dutyhosts dovecot: imap(support@dutyhosts.tk): Logged out in=70 out=633
Aug 25 12:44:10 dutyhosts dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=11106, secured, session=<dio+D7Otwtx/AAAB>
Aug 25 12:44:10 dutyhosts dovecot: imap(support@dutyhosts.tk): Logged out in=76 out=546
Aug 25 12:44:10 dutyhosts dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=11108, secured, session=<daxCD7OtxNx/AAAB>
Aug 25 12:44:10 dutyhosts dovecot: imap(support@dutyhosts.tk): Logged out in=120 out=766
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: 941C0A5586: from=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, size=542, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/trivial-rewrite[11099]: warning: do not list domain dutyhosts.tk in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: 79F61A5585: from=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, size=541, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: 1459AA5550: from=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, size=539, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/smtp[11115]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: admin@dutyhosts.tk
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/smtp[11116]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: admin@dutyhosts.tk
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/smtp[11117]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: admin@dutyhosts.tk
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/smtp[11100]: A6C04A558D: to=<silv3r.sc0rpion@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.197.26]:25, delay=5.9, delays=0.26/0.04/0.32/5.3, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.197.26] said: 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.26 information. r1si9530921qvm.98 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/cleanup[11095]: 7E798A558E: message-id=<20200825124412.7E798A558E@dutyhosts.tk>
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/bounce[11118]: A6C04A558D: sender non-delivery notification: 7E798A558E
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: 7E798A558E: from=<>, size=3210, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/trivial-rewrite[11099]: warning: do not list domain dutyhosts.tk in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: A6C04A558D: removed
Aug 25 12:44:12 dutyhosts postfix/smtp[11100]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: admin@dutyhosts.tk
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/master[10365]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 11115 exit status 1
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/master[10365]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/master[10365]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 11116 exit status 1
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/master[10365]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 11117 exit status 1
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/error[11121]: 941C0A5586: to=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, relay=none, delay=938, delays=937/1.2/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/error[11122]: 79F61A5585: to=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, relay=none, delay=999, delays=998/1.2/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/qmgr[10368]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/master[10365]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 11100 exit status 1
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/error[11121]: 1459AA5550: to=<dave@dutyhosts.tk>, relay=none, delay=571, delays=569/1.4/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
Aug 25 12:44:13 dutyhosts postfix/error[11124]: 7E798A558E: to=<support@dutyhosts.tk>, relay=none, delay=1.1, delays=0.02/1.1/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your server up according to the Perfect Server tutorial?